# glmnet: how to set reference category for multinomial logit

Tags: r, classification, logistic-regression, glmnet

Following my question in Cross Validate [glmnet: which is the reference category or class in multinomial regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125235/glmnet-which-is-the-reference-category-or-class-in-multinomial-regression), can someone explain how can we set the **reference category** in glmnet for multinomial logistic regression?

Even though glmnet is for applying shrinking methods (Ridge, Lasso, etc.) neither its documentation nor glmnet forums out there answer this question.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well no you cannot do that in the function glmnet but you can do that very easily just before you run the function using model.matrix:

```
a <- factor( rep(c("cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "no-cat"),50) ) #make a factor
levels(a) <- c("no-cat", "cat1", "cat2", "cat3") #change the order of the levels because 
#the first category is always the reference category using the model.matrix function
df <- data.frame(a) #put the factor in a dataframe

dummy_a <- model.matrix(~a,data=df) #make dummies for the factor. 
#Note the first category of the levels(a) will get excluded i.e. 
#become the reference category

cat_dummified <- dummy_a[,2:4] #the first column is the intercept i.e. a column of 1s
#which we exclude here

> head(cat_dummified)
  acat1 acat2 acat3
1     0     0     0
2     1     0     0
3     0     1     0
4     0     0     1
5     0     0     0
6     1     0     0

> class(cat_dummified)
[1] "matrix"
```

`cat_dummified` is also of `class matrix`, ready to use in the `glmnet` function.
This way you have only 3 dummies for which you will have coefficients and are referenced against the no-cat category.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, thanks for your response ! so this `cat_dummified` is the response `y` parameter in, for instance, the following `cv.glmnet` command?: `cv.fit = cv.glmnet(x = vars_matrix_data, y = cat_dummified, family = "multinomial", nfolds = 10, alpha = 1)` or is it part of the `x` matrix since you say it will have 3 coefficients ?

Comment: It is part of the x matrix since it will have 3 coefficients since you will use it as a predictive variable. But this is to get an idea on how to construct dummies making reference variables. Use it as you please!

Comment: So, has this been helpful? Would you like any additional info?

Comment: Thanks for keeping in touch. It doesn't work ... I think it's due to the nature of my `x` matrix (4694 obs x 1815 vars), it's a very sparse matrix with (independent) binary variables {0,1}. Each variable has at least 5 "1s". GLMNET finishes too early with non zero coefficients **only on dummy variables**. I'm editing my post so you can look at the matrix. I've used the Matrix package's sparse matrix type for `x` to save resources.

Comment: I don't get the question here. The reference category is the one that you leave outside. In this case the dummy_no_cat. All the other dummies (dummy_cat1,dummy_cat2,dummy_cat3) are referenced against the one excluded. this happens automatically since wherever those 3 are 0 an 1 is implied for dummy_no_cat. You don't need to explicitly say to glmnet which one was the one left outside. Unless I 'm missing something. It seems to me that the transformed matrix you have above is ready to use (at least according to the first 3 columns)

Comment: I'm surely the one who's missing something (it happens often): if you look at the dummified matrix, the `dummy_no_cat` has been excluded, and all observations having dummy_no_cat as class have 0 in all other three `dummy_catx` variables. To be honest, I couldn't apply your `model.matrix()` function, thus based on the structure of your dummified matrix, I've dummified the manually with R.

Comment: I don't know why the model.matrix() was always returning `Intercept, dummy_cat1, dummy_no-cat, dummt_cat3` ... I've tried putting the factor levels in the right order (following your script) but could get the expected one: `Intercept, dummy_cat1, dummy_cat2, dummt_cat3`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65944/discussion-between-guzu92-and-lyzander).